# when i get the contacts it's make an exception?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts

am going to read 5- Contacts , So i get this code and go smooth and no error occurred,
But when i add this two line for save the Name and contact to use them later , this exception appeared !!

this is the code :

```
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        String hasPhone = cursor
                .getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
        name = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

        // You know it has a number so now query it like this
        Cursor phones1 = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = "
                        + contactId, null, null);
        if (count > 5)
            break;
        while (phones1.moveToNext()) {
            phoneNumber = phones1
                    .getString(phones1
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));


        }

        phones1.close();


        Toast.makeText(this,
                contactId + " __ " + name + " # :  " + phoneNumber,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Contact2[count] = name;
        Numbers2[count] = phoneNumber;
        count++;

    }
```

the two statements cause the exception !!

```
Contact2[count] = name;
Numbers2[count] = phoneNumber;
```

however the code go well without these statements .

this are the logcat window

```
06-15 18:00:02.745: I/ApplicationPackageManager(8639): cscCountry is not German : XEU
06-15 18:00:03.586: W/dalvikvm(8639): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught   exception (group=0x4001d560)
06-15 18:00:03.586: E/AndroidRuntime(8639): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-15 18:00:03.586: E/AndroidRuntime(8639): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not  execute method of the activity
06-15 18:00:03.586: E/AndroidRuntime(8639):     at  android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2154)
06-15 18:00:03.586: E/AndroidRuntime(8639):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
06-15 18:00:03.586: E/AndroidRuntime(8639):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
06-15 18:00:03.586: E/AndroidRuntime(8639):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587) 
06-15 18:00:03.586: E/AndroidRuntime(8639):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-15 18:00:03.586: E/AndroidRuntime(8639):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-15 18:00:03.586: E/AndroidRuntime(8639):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
06-15 18:00:03.586: E/AndroidRuntime(8639):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-15 18:00:03.586: E/AndroidRuntime(8639):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-15 18:00:03.586: E/AndroidRuntime(8639):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
06-15 18:00:03.586: E/AndroidRuntime(8639):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
06-15 18:00:03.586: E/AndroidRuntime(8639):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-15 18:00:03.586: E/AndroidRuntime(8639): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-15 18:00:03.586: E/AndroidRuntime(8639):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-15 18:00:03.586: E/AndroidRuntime(8639):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-15 18:00:03.586: E/AndroidRuntime(8639):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2149)
06-15 18:00:03.586: E/AndroidRuntime(8639):     ... 11 more
06-15 18:00:03.586: E/AndroidRuntime(8639): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-15 18:00:03.586: E/AndroidRuntime(8639):     at oo.k.TestActivity.upload(TestActivity.java:156)
```

i just neeed to save the Contact result.

Comment: You haven't shown how Contact2 and Numbers2 are defined. Are they arrays or Lists? Have you constructed/initialized them properly?

Comment: String[] Contact2 = null;
 String[] Numbers2 = null;

Comment: please post TestActivity.upload() Method with line numbers

Comment: try String Contact2 = new String[COUNT]

Comment: Do you ever initialize them? As in: Contact2 = new String[5];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're getting a Null Pointer Exception, probably because you haven't initialized your arrays `Contact2` and `Numbers2`.

```
Contact2 = new String[5];
```